# How to parse datetime that ends with `Z`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, strptime

I have the following datetime string `s`:

`2017-10-18T04:46:53.553472514Z`

I parse it like that:

```
t = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

how to fix *ValueError: time data `'2017-10-18T04:46:53.553472514Z'` does not match format `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'`*

Comment: You don't have the `T` and the fraction of the second in your format string.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: @KlausD. how to add fraction to `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'`?

Comment: Just to point out, your datetime string is in ISO8601 format.

Comment: partly duplicate of [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/10197418) - use strptime's `%z` (lower-case z).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In theory,

```
t = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

would be the correct format string as you have fractions of second as well. BUT they would then need to be microseconds. Yours are probably nanoseconds, as `%f` only takes maximum of 6 digits.

So you need to do something like this:

```
t = datetime.datetime.strptime(s.split(".")[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
t = t + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=int(s.split(".")[1][:-1])/1000)

print (t)
```

This works but it converts nanoseconds to microseconds. If this is not ok, then you need to do something else.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should use dateutil.parser module

```
In [23]: s = "2017-10-18T04:46:53.553472514Z"

In [24]: import dateutil.parser as p

In [25]: p.parse(s)
Out[25]: datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 18, 4, 46, 53, 553472, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@FObersteiner pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906432/how-to-parse-datetime-that-ends-with-z#comment132715746_69657037), `%z` parses `Z` as well as `±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]` style of timezone encoding.

This information is hidden in the [technical detail](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/datetime.html#technical-detail) #6. :-/

Previous incorrect answer:

> To answer the original question: there's no way to parse "Z" as the timezone using only the standard library.~
>
> Here's some discussion on that: https://bugs.python.org/issue35829

Comment: `%z` *does* parse Z.

Comment: In `datetime.strptime`, `%z` parses the UTC offset in the form `±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]`. See https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to this post. Please note the [technical detail](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/datetime.html#technical-detail) #6, "*[...] In addition, providing 'Z' is identical to '+00:00'*".

Comment: You are 100% correct!

Answer (score 0):

`datetime` is another Python built-in module that is completely superseded by a better extra module: [`arrow`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

You can just do:

```
import arrow
dt = arrow.get('2017-10-18T04:46:53.553472514Z').datetime
```

Your date string being in standardized ISO format, it will be parsed without even giving a format string. The parsed `df` will be:

> datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 18, 4, 46, 53, 553472, tzinfo=tzutc())

Or keep the `Arrow` object in case you want to keep the extra precision

Comment: Who decides that a built-in module is superseded by a random external module?

Comment: @km6: basically, it's you who decide if you prefer to use only the standard library + your own code to fill the gaps, or if you want to rely on external modules that will make your life easier. But it is generally admitted that the standard library is the place where modules go to die. Once in the standard library, they don't evolve much. Some good examples: urllib.request is obsoleted by requests/httpx (to the point that even the official doc recommends to use it: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request ). LXML implements a much faster xml parser. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I like the [mx.DateTime module](https://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/).

```
import mx.DateTime as dt
dt.DateTimeFrom('2017-10-18T04:46:53.553472514Z')
```